# Comparison of the portrayal of the female role in society between Jane Eyre and Tess?

Tags: thomas-hardy, charlotte-bronte, jane-eyre, tess-of-the-durbervilles

I really can't get the differences of the female role in society and how they are seen by their families and by the society in general.

How can we compare the portrayal of the female role in society between *Jane Eyre* and *Tess of the D'Urbervilles*?